# With VirtualBox, how does my system's CPU map to the virtual machine?

Tags: parallel-processing, virtual-machine, virtualbox, cpu, cpu-cores

On my Mac, I have 8 cores working when I run `htop`.

I can `modifyvm` to have 8 cores in my virtual machine as well, but is it a one to one mapping?

Thus, if I set 4 virtual cores, do I have the power of 4 physical cores or do I have the power of 8 distributed on 4? Hence, does it make sense to have multiple cores in a vm regarding the overall performance or does it only make sense if you have processes that do not work well without parallelisation?